# Dataset after merging gives float values and cannot change to Int

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, integer

I have two dataset,

```
df1

100

20


30


5





df2

3

4


5

6
```

When i try to merge
df3=pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, ignore_index= False)

I get the output as :

```
df1  df2

100.0  3
20.0   4
30.0   5
5.0    6
```

It gets automatically changed to float, and .astype("Int64"), doesnot change the float, is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: `df1` and `df2` are probably not the same length, so the sorter row is filled with `np.nan` and `np.nan` can't be converted by `.astype(int)`. You can `.dropna` or `fillna` and then change the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and see:

```
df3.astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unable to reproduce your output

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [100,20,30,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"b": [3,4,5,6]})
df3=pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, ignore_index= False)
print(df3)

     a  b
0  100  3
1   20  4
2   30  5
3    5  6
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the output of `df1.info()` and `df2.info()`?
And `print(df1.to_csv(index=False))` and `print(df2.to_csv(index=False))`?

That helps in reproducing the issue.

Seems to work fine without further details:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[100,20,30,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B':[3,4,5,6]})
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, ignore_index= False)
print(df3)
```

Result:

```
     A  B
0  100  3
1   20  4
2   30  5
3    5  6
```